# How to allow only a number format(digits and decimal point) in the corresponding texfield uisng AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I need a directive for this format

Eg 423.33 is valid number 423.333 is invalid allowed only positive numbers including 0.
But user should not to enter 0423.33

if it write only number without decimal then get the output as given below
423 gets formatted as 423.00

Remember should no NEGATIVES and allow only number format with decimal max=2

Please help me for getting this I am beginner in AngularJs support me Thank you

This is my code the problem is when initially run I enter characters(other than number) in two times it will allowed.  For Eg press 'W' in two times it will allwed in that textfield.Please correct it. I dont know how to post it in JFiddle

Here is my code

script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('nksOnlyNumber', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {   
     scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var spiltArray = String(newValue).split("");

        if(attrs.allowNegative == "false") {
          if(spiltArray[0] == '-') {
        newValue = newValue.replace("-", "");
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
        ngModel.$render();
          }
        }

        if(attrs.allowDecimal == "false") {
        newValue = parseInt(newValue);
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
        ngModel.$render();
        }

        if(attrs.allowDecimal != "false") {
          if(attrs.decimalUpto) {
         var n = String(newValue).split(".");
         if(n[1]) {
            var n2 = n[1].slice(0, attrs.decimalUpto);
            newValue = [n[0], n2].join(".");
            ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
            ngModel.$render();
         }
          }
        }

        if(attrs.loading=="one"){
         // attr.$set("ngTrim", "false");
          var limitLength = parseInt(attrs.awLimitLength, 10);// console.log(attrs);
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) {
        if(ngModel.$viewValue.length>limitLength){
          ngModel.$setViewValue( ngModel.$viewValue.substring(0, limitLength ) );
          ngModel.$render();
        }
          });             
        }  


        if (spiltArray.length === 0) return;
        if (spiltArray.length === 1 && (spiltArray[0] == '-' || spiltArray[0] === '.' )) return;
        if (spiltArray.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;

          /*Check it is number or not.*/
          if (isNaN(newValue)) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
        ngModel.$render();
          }
      });
      }
  };
});
```

view.jsp

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group ">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i>
                    </span> 
                    <b>Number Only</b><br>
                    <input type="text"  nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber"/><br>

                    <b>NumberLimited Only 2 Digits</b><br>
                    <input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber6" aw-limit-length="2" loading="one" /><br>

                    <b>Decimal Upto 2</b><br>
                    <input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber1" decimal-upto="2" /><br>

                    <b>Allow Negative</b><br>
                <input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber2" decimal-upto="2" allow-negative="true" /><br>

                <b>Not Allow Negative</b><br>
                <input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber3" decimal-upto="2" allow-negative="false" /><br>

                    <b>Not Allow Decimal</b><br>
                <input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber4" allow-decimal="false" /><br>

                <b>Allow Decimal</b><br>
                <input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber5" allow-decimal="true" /><br>


                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: First, you should use an `input type="number"` and allow the browser to do the majority of the work for you here.  Trying to write your own rules for all the possible combinations is a fools errand, and doesn't even account for other cultures, where the role of `,` and `.` are reversed, for example.  If you *absolutely have no other choice*, then you should consider using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you can use [`Number`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) inbuilt filter. It will work as you expect for this situation. You should make type as `number` and set `min=1` attribute to avoid negative numbers. Your HTML snippet would be

```
<label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val' type="number" min="1"></label>
<span id='number-default'>{{val | number : 2}}</span>
```

If user types `423.333` it will automatically convert in 2 fraction size. So your output will be for some cases as defined below:

```
0422 => 422.00
000422.33 => 422.33
422.333 => 422.33
422.339 => 422.34
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Vineet Good .But i need to edit my code .Its working code only few issues on that y can able to edit that i think.In your code user can able to enter negative values but in my code user cant to write thats the difference..In my code you see there is  a number imit actually i used it for phone number validation. I set it as 10 if user cant able to write that imit.I hope you will help me.You code is good.Ok..

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-pattern if you want specific pattern to be allowed in the input field. Use the REGEX for the pattern you want to match. For example :

```
<input ng-model='val' type="text" ng-pattern="/[^0]\d.(\d{1,2})+/">
```

Check the documentation for more help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: Dear Nehaji can you edit my code.Is it possible to you.Thankyou.If you give me your mail id i will send entire code to you..